# How can I run an AsyncTask with a dialog after finishing activity?

Tags: android

I have two activities, one for displaying entries and another for creating them. Here's a standard use case:

- User opens app and it displays entries.
- User clicks button to create new entry and it opens the new activity.
- User finishes creating entry and clicks "Done".
- Activity finishes with setResult() and finish().

What I want to add is an AsyncTask that runs after the viewing activity is **completely loaded.** This AsyncTask shows a dialog while it's running. The problem is, when I put this code into onActivityResult() like this:

```
@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
        switch(resultCode) { 
        case (Activity.RESULT_OK): {
            mEntryListFragment.updateContent();
            runAsyncTaskHere();
        }
    }
}
```

It runs the AsyncTask before it goes back to the main activity, and no dialog shows. Any ideas what I can do?

Edit: here's the AsyncTask.

```
public static class LogInTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    protected String username = "";
    protected String password = "";
    protected ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected boolean showDialogs;

    public LogInTask(boolean sd) {
        this.showDialogs = sd;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (this.showDialogs) dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.getContext(), null, "Logging in...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... login) {
        if (Config.DEBUG) Log.d(Config.APP_NAME, "in doInBackground() of LogInTask");
        HttpResponse response = null;
        String username = login[0];
        String password = login[1];
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL_BASE + URL_LOGIN);

            // main (JSON) login method
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject().put("user", 
                    new JSONObject()
                        .put("email", username)
                        .put("password", password)
                        .put("remember_me", Config.REMEMBER_LOGIN)
                    );
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            String responseEntity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(responseEntity);
            return result.getBoolean("success") ? 1 : KEY_ERROR; // Return 1 if successful and -1 if not
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            KEY_ERROR;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return KEY_ERROR;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if (this.showDialogs) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            String text = result == 1 ? "Login was successful." : "Login failed!";
            makeToast(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 2: I tried this:

```
boolean needToUpdate = false;
@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    switch(resultCode) { 
        case (Activity.RESULT_OK): {
            mEntryListFragment.updateContent();
            needToUpdate = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (needToUpdate) {
        runAsyncTaskHere();
        mEntryListFragment.updateContent();
    }
    needToUpdate = false;
}
```

and it did the same thing.

Edit 3: here're the relevant sections of the AndroidManifest:

```
 <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddEntryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you click on the Button to create new Entry, launch New Activity. but keep the Activity with entries. do not call finish() after intent.
2. After creation, and on clicking DONE, just close the Current Activity.(call finish())
3. mEntryListFragment.updateContent write this method in onStart() of the activity displaying entries.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't change anything; I can't figure out what's doing this!

Comment: you have to fetch the entries again and set the List's adapter to reflect changes(addition of the new entry) in mEntryListFragment.updateContent() method

Comment: i assume you are getting the entries using an asynctask(may be fetching from DB). or whatever you are using to create entries for the list adapter should be placed in updateContent() and listview.setAdapter(your adapter) must be called at the end. I hope you and i are on same track, and i have understood your problem properly.

Comment: mostly - I'm getting the entries from a SQLite database, and the AsyncTask is uploading them to a server. The issue is that the AsyncTask is freezing the UI thread without displaying a ProgressDialog like it's supposed to.

Comment: does your SQLite DB sync with the server.? I mean when you add an entry to server using async task, does your SQLite DB get updated as well. if so, loading the content into listview using updateContent() method having listview.setAdapter() must show changes as required.

Comment: When I add an entry, the AsyncTask adds some values from the JSON the server returns to the database, yes. But what do you mean by 'must show changes as required'?

Comment: when the json returned from the server is used to update the content in SQLite DB, then after when you return back to Main activity(after closing the Add Entry activity) onStart()/onResume() method will be called. so, if your updateContent() method is called inside that, then obviously the list entries should have the new entry you last entered. agree?

Comment: Yeah they do. They even do with the bug this post is about, just not until after the AsyncTask finishes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26642/discussion-between-santhosh-and-cornholio)

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncTask` is a class for background processing, please, don't try to use it to do something with your UI or Activities, it **always** leads to a bad and unpredictable behaviour.

Maybe I should elaborate a little. Activities come and go, get killed and restored, destroyed and recreated as a usual way of theirs lives. It's absolutely normal.

Your `AsyncTask` may easily outlive your `Activity`, so when you're trying to access UI, it's already gone. Destroyed and recreated again, and all you've got is a dead pointer, which gives you an exception. Load your files in `AsyncTask`, do networking, access database. Just don't try to access UI/Activities, or your application will eventually crash and burn.

Comment: If that's the case, where should I do networking? That's where I've always read that I should do networking tasks.

Comment: do your networking in `AsyncTask`, but don't do UI stuff there.

Comment: That's what I thought. The only UI stuff I'm doing in mine is a ProgressDialog, as my code shows. I really just need to figure out why it's running before the second activity finishes and is replaced by the first.

Comment: you need a context for progress dialog, and by the time your data loading complete your user might have pressed "home" button or rotated the device, and your `Activity` (and its `Context`) is gone. Guess, what will happen when you try to do anything with dead context...

Comment: This app is locked to portrait orientation - but I see where you're coming from. Where, then, should I put my ProgressDialog?

Comment: if you can avoid it, you'd better not use any progress dialogs at all -- these are very boring to watch for your users. if you have a long task to do -- offload it to AsyncTask and forget about it -- no need to show any progress, your users might have something more interesting to do. if you have a very long list you'd like to get dynamically loaded, you may check `AsyncLoader`, which is closely coupled with the `Activity` and gets killed at the same moment the activity dies.

Comment: I see - I'll certainly consider this, as it looks like a pretty important part of the app design. Thanks a bunch for the help, you'll get upvoted as soon as I have the rep :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) to achieve this.Start the dialog onPreExecute() and finish it onPostExecute() methods.You have to override those methods in your async task.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm doing it already. Give me a sec, I'll post my asynctask code as well.

Comment: then call your method in onResume. You can use flag if it's passed through onActivityResult() method.

Comment: And btw what is the task of your activities?If you use single task you can't have onActivityResult().Other thing is do you really want to have static context in your MainActivty?

Comment: I am sure that showDialogs is true, yes. What do you mean by what is the task of my Activities? I launch my second activity with `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);` and I know for sure that onActivityResult is running.

Comment: Can you post the activity's declaration in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: I added both activities' declarations to the OP.

Comment: And what does MainActivity.getContext() returns?You should give the current activity's context(this).So try to change MainActivity.getContext() with this (if you executing the code within some activity)

Comment: It's returning some valid context, because it runs the AsyncTask fine, but it runs BEFORE the first activity is shown again and it freezes the whole application for the duration. I tried replacing it with this and it did the same thing once again.

Answer (score 0):

i think , you have to use Concept of callbacks ,

like when ever , loading is complete , implement your `callback` inside which you can deal with `AsyncTask` and after performing your task inside `doInBackGround()` , you can use `onPostExecute()` .

try something like this ,

```
Callback_interface
{
    void async_run_after_some_time() ;
}

main_activity_class extends Activity Implements Callback_interface
{
    void async_run_after_some_time()
    {
        // implement your toast here 
    }
}

onPostExecute()
{
    main_activity_class ob = new main_activity_class ();
    ob.async_run_after_some_time();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.

1. Are you sure you are retrieving the proper context.
2. Is the boolean set correctly?

Plus, I do believe you are using HttpCore. From what I remember it requires some more attention networking and dis/connection wise due to it's granularity (compared to the HttpConnection class available by default). As such I don't think it is the best to use it with AsyncTask classes since they have little connection with the UI thread. Thus don't give much control for the user and may live beyond application's lifespan.

Comment: I think it must be the context, but I'm not sure, and yes the boolean is correct.